# disable http auth for specific rewritten location

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, authentication

I need to setup apache to inverse match /admin location which is rewritten by default drupal htacess file. Simply ask for http auth for everything that is not /admin/*

I've tried this so far:

```
   < LocationMatch "^/(?!admin)" >

    AuthName "Members Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user

    < /LocationMatch >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a SetEnvIf to check Request_URI for /admin, so you should end up with something like this:

```
# Set an environment variable if requesting /admin
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin/? DONT_NEED_AUTH=true

# Setup your auth mechanism
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd

# Set the allow/deny order
Order Deny,Allow

# Indicate that any of the following will satisfy the Deny/Allow
Satisfy any

# First off, deny from all
Deny from all

# Allow outright if this environment variable is set
Allow from env=DONT_NEED_AUTH

# or require a valid user
Require valid-user
```

You may need to wrap that in the appropriate  or  tags if you are not putting this inside a .htaccess file.

Comment: i tried these inside Directory tags for my /var/www, resulting in requiring auth for every request

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `/admin` with what Drupal rewrites to? I'm not sure what module order takes precedence, mod-setenv or mod-rewrite

Comment: <pre>
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/admin/?$" do_auth=1

AuthName "Members Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=do_auth
Satisfy Any
</pre>
works, but i am unable to reverse it, thats what i need

Comment: What I posted works in my .htaccess, any request starting with /admin won't get authenticated, everything else will require authentication. That's what you mean by *Simply ask for http auth for everything that is not /admin/*, right?

Comment: If that's not the case and I read your question wrong, then use what I have except change the line `Allow from env=DONT_NEED_AUTH` to `Allow from env=!DONT_NEED_AUTH`

Comment: i will make a simple test without drupal in the tree i an not sure if its  .htaccess is messing the things

Comment: i've tested your solution on clean ubuntu install, its not working, however if i add env=!DONT_NEED_AUTH its matching admin and is asking for password for admin directory only. I also tried to craft a reverse regular expression but so far no luck also. Turning off mod_rewrite will allow everything from your suggestion to work properly with static directory /admin/. So i am facing some kind of conflict with rewrite itself.

Comment: I tried this as well, and the exception on the path will not kick in.

Comment: You're a savior!