# How to make Basic Auth exclude a rewritten URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

I have a Basic Authentication setup on a development server. It is setup inside my `httpd.conf` file for the VirtualHost of the website. I've had to set up it to exclude certain directories, which has caused no problems and all works fine.

The issue has been with excluding a URL that has been through my `mod_rewrite` rules in the `.htaccess` file. My set up is that I have all URLs going through my `index.php` file and from there the relevant code is found and ran. I tried adding the URL that I wanted to exclude (`/businesses/upload_logo`) like I did the others but it still requires authentication. This is what I currently have:

```
...
<Location />
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/businesses/upload_logo" noauth=1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api/.*" noauth=1

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private"
    AuthUserFile ****
    Require valid-user

    Order deny,allow
    Satisfy any
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=noauth
</Location>
....
```

I have found questions that are similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338567/disable-http-auth-for-specific-rewritten-location) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978080/htaccess-exclude-one-url-from-basic-auth) but the answers only give me what I'm already trying.

I have thought of possible other solutions as well, but these will be last resort things. I want to see if it's possible the way I'm currently doing it:

- Set up the basic auth inside my php code instead

  - Too much hassle at the moment
- Put the authentication in my `.htaccess` file instead

  - Didn't want to do this just yet as I only want the authentication to happen on one of 3 servers. I'm aware that I could use some more `SetEnvIf HOST ...` but I'm looking to see if it can be fixed this way or not first.

The `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Interesting. At first I thought it'd be doable by setting noauth in the rewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^upload_logo$ index.php [E=noauth:1]`, but that's a dead end, because of the [visibility of env vars](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/). The whole thing seems to arise because of the evaulation order of auth and mod_rewrite directives. It'd be nice if someone shed some light on this.

Comment: @SáT Yeah, I came to the same conclusion as you about the fact that it's the order of the auth and mod_rewrite rules being evaluated.

Comment: Would you mind if I put a bounty on this?

Comment: No I don't mind. Would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you also post the htaccess?

Comment: Just to be sure; the exclusion of some urls worked, until you added the htaccess?

Comment: @Gerben The exclusion of files/directories that exist work fine. It appears to be only on URLs that are rewritten through `mod_rewrite`. I will update my question to include the RewriteRule that's causing the issues a bit later when I'm near my computer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding

```
Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
```

Comment: Oh boy, how could I have forgotten that! Yes, the names of environmental variables set by RewriteRules are prefixed with `REDIRECT_` (which is a nuisance). @Josh, you could set the env var in the .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^upload_logo$ index.php [E=noauth:1,L,QSA]`, then allow from `REDIRECT_noauth`. Alternatively, and this may be a better approach, you could do something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [E=orig:%{REQUEST_URI}]`, then in the httpd.conf: `SetEnvIf REDIRECT_orig "/?businesses/upload_logo" noauth=1`.

Comment: I tried using both of your suggestions but I am unable to get it to work. I tried simplifying your idea @SáT by having `[E:orig:foo]` in my `.htaccess` rule and then using `SetEnvIf REDIRECT_orig "foo" noauth=1` (this should mean that all requests don't require a password) and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: So what would be full config?

Comment: @bluszcz just take the code from the question, but replace the second last line.

Comment: I love your Gerben. Saved my day.

Comment: >but replace the second last line
- don't replace, but add

Answer (score 2):

For me something like this works like a charm:

```
<location />
        SetEnvIf Request_URI "/businesses/upload_logo" REDIRECT_noauth=1
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Files"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwords/passwords
        Order Deny,Allow
        Satisfy any
        Deny from all
        Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
        Require user yournickname
</location>
```

Answer (score -1):

based on what you have given it should work, unless there is a conflicting directive somewhere else in your configuration.

i have made a similar working setup , just i have used filesystem path instead of URI

i am adding it here, hoping you may find it useful

```
<VirtualHost *:8989 >
<IfModule mod_auth_basic.c>
 <Directory /var/www/html/vella-8989>
  # the auth block
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Please login."
  AuthUserFile /var/www/html/vella-8989/.htpasswd
  require valid-user

  Order Deny,Allow
  Satisfy any
  Deny from all
  Require valid-user
  Allow from env=noauth
</Directory>
</IfModule>
  # set an environtment variable "noauth" if the request has "/callbacks/"
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "/callbacks/" noauth=1
  ServerName vella.com
  ServerSignature off
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is so bad - you have htpasswd file inside your /var/www/html directory.

Comment: @bluszcz why is it *so bad*?