# Apache - RewriteCond QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've searched over here something close to what i need, havent found. So there we go.
I've got a MediaWiki, the MediaWiki vhost uses mod_authnz_ldap to authenticate via LDAP, however, the Collection extension (creates PDF), when I click to generate the pdf file, it send a request to Apache, when this happens, Apache ask it for Authentication getting no answer, and  it returns an error.
This is the error that i got in the render:

```
ERR: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
ERR: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
ERR: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
ERR: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

I'm trying to use QUERY_STRING to search for the string "writer=rl" or "render" or whatever, those are strings that come in the "Create PDF request".
I'm using like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^writer=rl$
RewriteRule .* - [E=free_access]
```

Where "free_access" is my enviromnent variable.

Then, i'm doing like this:

```
     AllowOverride All
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Order deny,allow
     deny from all
     allow from env=free_access
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Wiki - Autenticacao via LDAP"
     AuthBasicProvider ldap
     AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
     AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
     AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xxx.yyy.zzz.www:389/ou=users,dc=dc,dc=BLABLA,dc=UN?uid?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)"
     AuthLDAPRemoteUserIsDN off
     AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
     Require valid-user
     Satisfy any
```

Well, i cant get it working with this, anyone have ever did work?

Comment: If you are using mod_rewrite, then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950207/how-to-make-basic-auth-exclude-a-rewritten-url/14010456#14010456

Comment: After looking at it some more, I think mod_auth_ldap and apache's default access control (`allow`) don't mix.